# From a purely caching point of view, is there any advantage using the new Cache API instead of regular http cache?

Tags: caching, service-worker, browser-cache, progressive-web-apps

The arrival of service workers has led to a great number of improvements to the web. There are many use cases for service workers.
However, from a purely caching point of view, does it makes sense to use the Cache API?

Many approaches make assumptions of how resources will be handled.
Often only the URL is used to determine how the resource should be handled with strategies such as Network first, Network Only, Stale-while-revalidate, Cache first and Cache only. This can be tedious work, because you have to define a specific handler for many URLs. It's not scalable.

Instead I was thinking of using regular HTTP cache in combination with the Cache API. Response headers contain useful information that can be used to cache and verify if the cache can still be used or if a new version would be available. Together with best practice caching (for example https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/), this could create a generic service worker that has not te be updated when resources change.
Based on the response headers, a resource could be handled by a custom handler. If the headers would ever be updated, it would be possible to handle the resource with a different handler if necessary.

But then I realised, I was just reimplementing browser cache with the Cache API. This would mean that the resources would be cached double (take this with a grain of salt), by storing it in both the browser and the service worker cache. Additionally, while the Cache API provides more control, most handlers can be (sort of) simulated with http cache:

- Network only: Cache-Control: no-store
- Cache only: Cache-Control: immutable
- Cache first: Cache-Control: max-age with validation (Etag, Last Modified, ...)
- Stale-while-revalidate: Cache-Control: stale-while-revalidate

I don't immediately see how to simulate network first, but then again this would imply support for offline usage (or bad connection). (Keep in mind, this is not the use case I'm looking for).
While it's always useful to provide a fallback (using service workers & Cache API), is it worth having the resources possibly cached double and having copied the browser's caching logic? I'm aware that the Cache API can be used to precache resources, but I think these could also be precached by requesting them in advance.

Lastly, I know the browser is in charge of managing the browser cache and a developer has limited control over it (using HTTP Cache headers).
But the browser could also choose to remove the whole service worker cache to clear disk space. There are ways to make sure the cache persists, but that's not the point here.

My questions are:

- What advantages has the Cache API that can't be simulated with regular browser cache?
- What could be cached with the Cache API, but not with regular browser cache?
- Is there another way to create a service worker that does not need to be updated

Answer (score 0):

What advantages has the Cache API that can't be simulated with regular browser cache?

CacheAPI have been created to be manipulated by Service Worker, so you can do nearly what you want with it, be you can't interfere or do anything to HTTP cache, it's all in browser mechanic, i'm not sure but HTTP cache is completly wreck when your offline, not CacheAPI.

What could be cached with the Cache API, but not with regular browser cache?

Before caching request, you can alter request to fit your need, or even cache response with `Cache-Control: 0` if you want. Even store custom data that will need after.

Is there another way to create a service worker that does not need to be updated

It need a bit of work, be two of solution to achieve that is :

- On each page call you communicate with SW using postMessage to compare version (it can be an id, a hash or even whole list of assets), it's different, you can load list of ressource from given location then add it to cache. (Due to javascript use, this won't work if you have to make it work from AMP)
- Each time a user load a page, or each 10/20min ( or both, whatever you want ), you call a files to know your assert version, if it's different, you do the same thing on the other solution.

Hope I help